# Mapping a single uniform random variable to a uniform product random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a single random variable $X\sim \operatorname{Uniform}(0,1)$.

I would like a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $F = f(X)$ has the distribution

\begin{equation}
p_F(y) = \begin{cases}
{(-\log y)^n \over n!} & \text{if } 0 < y \leq 1 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

for some given $n$ (i.e., the product distribution for $n+1$ independent random variables).

Does such an $f$ exist? If so what is it? I tried reverse-engineering one directly but became hopelessly tangled in incomplete gamma functions and the like.

Thanks!

Comment: Theoretically, by Inverse Transform Sampling, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling
such function $f$ do exist and is the inverse of the CDF / Quantile function. However such function often does not has closed-form expression.

Comment: $$ \int_0^1 (-\log y)^n \, dy = n!\ne(n-1)!. $$

Comment: Even for $n=1$ you may need the Lambert W function

Comment: @MichaelHardy - yes my mistake, thanks, have corrected the question